# If $a$ is a unit, prove that $ax \equiv b (\bmod n)$ has a unique solution

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

The whole question is:

If $a, b \in \mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z$ and $a$ is a unit, prove that $ax = b$ has a unique solution in $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$.

I know it has something to do with $au=1$ for some $u \in \mathbb Z$ but I don't know how to apply it.

Any help is welcome, thank you!

Comment: Use MathJax for formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $au=1$, what is $a(ub)$? That settles existence.

As for uniqueness, suppose $ax=b$ and $ay=b$. We want to show that $x=y$, i.e. $x-y=0$. We have $a(x-y)=ax-ay=b-b=0$; so now we have to show that if $av=0$ for some $v$, then $v$ must be zero. But if $av=0$, then $v=(au)v=(av)u=0\cdot u=0$.